# Mongoose, can't update an array element: "key ...$... must not contain '.'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a node app using mongoose.
In my mongoose schema I use an array of images, which are objects with properties. Something like:

```
const schemaPeople = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  images: [{
    url: {
      type: String
    },
    etag: {
      type: String
    },
  }],
});

const Person = mongoose.model('people', schemaPeople);
```

I have my collection full of persons, each with a name and an array of images, each one with it's url property.
When I download an image for a person, I'd like to update it in the database with come additional properties, for example 'etag'. So I do something like:

```
personName = 'Alice';
imageDownloaded = {
  url: 'https://www.example.com/image1.jpg',
  etag: '123457890',
};
Person.updateOne(
  { name: personName, "images": { "$elemMatch": { "url": imageDownloaded.url } } },
  { $set: { "images.$.etag": imageDownloaded.etag } },
  function(err, result) {}
);
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: key images.$.etag must not contain '.'
   at serializeInto (./node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:917:19)
   ...
```

I cannot find any useful reference to this issue on the web, so I suppose I am missing something obvious... Can anybody help?

Any suggestion about a modification of the design of the schema will be welcome, too... I'm quite new in noSQL database design...

I use mongoose 5.9.27 and mongodb 3.5.10 modules.

**UPDATE**:
I did just found the origin of the problem... I was using a plugin for my collection (to keep an history of changes to the collection): it is `mongoose-history` (v0.8.0).

```
// plugins
schemaPeople.plugin(mongooseHistory, {
  customCollectionName: name + "History",
  indexes: [{ 't': -1, 'd._id': 1 }],
}); // add support for history of changes
```

Removing the plugin everything works just fine...

Possibly the reason is for that plugin the `update` handling is yet in progress... I did just file an [issue](https://github.com/nassor/mongoose-history/issues/64) to the project.

Thanks anybody for helping... I beg your pardon, the solution could not be found with only the info I gave about the issuue.

Comment: I think the issue is version not sure, look at the [mongodb v3.4 no longer support](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/update/positional/) might it is from 3.6, and second option is [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#syntax) but it is from mongodb v3.6 as well.

Comment: It's easy, but I don't understand one thing about your question. Do you want to add a total new object inside that array? or just update the etag of an exiting image?

Comment: @turivishal: if I understand correctly your comment, I don't think it's an issue related to modules versions: I did just upgrade to latest mongoose (5.11.9) and mongodb (3.6.3), same error... Or do you mean I should downgrade? I'd prefer a solution for current mongoose/mongodb versions...

Comment: @kevin-buguecio: I want to update an existing item... In the example, 'url' property exists already, and I want to update 'etag' value...

Comment: i think you misunderstood, sorry for my sentence, update query is supports $ from mongodb v3.6, I am not getting you exactly what is *mongodb module*? you mean npm? can you confirm just mongodb version not npm. look at this working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IR8N-egwJU-) in latest version.

Comment: @turivishal: Yes, I mean npm versions. MongoDB version:
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8

Comment: Mongodb server version and mongodb shell version both are different, can you confirm mongodb server version,  you can see mongo server version when you connect mongo shell using `mongo` command and second way is after connecting with shell use `db.version()` command.

Comment: for easy understanding just look at [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5alP.png) marked area in version, it will help you.

Comment: @turivishal: db.version() is 3.6.8, too.
Thanks for the playground, it's exactly what I'm doing... There it works, for me it does not... :-(

Comment: One question, this is the only query with this values that send error? Or with find() (for example) is also making trouble?

Comment: I did not try with find()... I'll try ASAP... Now it's almost midnight here... :-)

Comment: Have you resolved problem? jus try updating mongoose npm and mongodb to latest version. there was one [issue-7144](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7144) in mongoose 5.1.5, but it has been resolved, it looks same error message like yours.

Comment: just upload your sample project/code in github, if you really want to, i will try to resolve if anything i can do.

Comment: @turivishal: thanks for your help. I did just find the origin of the problem... Will update my question with the solution soon... Submitted an issue to the relevant module mantainer.

Comment: Great, you found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it:

```
Person.updateOne(
        { name: personName },
        { $set: { "images.$[imageurl].etag": imageDownloaded.etag } }, {
        "arrayFilters": [
            { "imageurl.url": imageDownloaded.url }
        ]
    },
        function (err, result) { 
        //manage error and result
    }
);
```

Comment: Also trying this solution, I always get "Error: key images.$[imageurl].etag must not contain '.'" ... :-(

Comment: Then looking turivishal and other info that I've read it seems that you've an outdated version of MongoDB or Mongoshell

Comment: arrayFilters is also support from mongodb v3.6 that i was already mention in first comment.

Comment: @Kevin-Bugecio: mongodb shell and MongoDB version() is both 3.6.8... It is not possible to update an array item in 3.6 ?